# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Im getting this error, i read many articles with this error, my problem coming by my web service, i only want to know how i can get Exception in my Background work and show toast or message, im trying with adding throws to my method, using Try{}Catch(), but i cant show message and  ever time "My App Stop Working".

transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); this is where my app crash.

The exception is RuntimeException but i dont know why my TryCatch do nothing and my app crash.

```
           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("CIA", g.getCia());
            request.addProperty("BD", BD);
            request.addProperty("CODE", g.getCode());

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
            transport.debug = true;
            transport.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // HERE IS RUNTIME EXCEPTION OCCURRED


            SoapObject resSoap = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            int count= 0;
            if (resSoap != null) {
                count= resSoap.getPropertyCount();
                clearList();
            }
            String cod_prod, desc_prod, unit;
            if (count> 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    SoapObject ic = (SoapObject) resSoap.getProperty(i);

                    cod_prod = ic.getProperty("COD_PROD").toString();
                    desc_prod = ic.getProperty("PROD_DESC").toString();
                    unit= ic.getProperty("UNIT").toString();

                    listUbi.addProduct(cod_prod, desc_prod, unit);

                }
                flag= true;
                c.close();
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Exception stack trace

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That would include the complete Java stack trace associated with your crash, plus the Java code referenced in that stack trace.

Comment: Edited and showing where is my exception